# [MapPoint updateFramerate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I am getting this error when I am trying to redraw the MKMapView. I used breakpoints and when the app crash it stops in this line:

```
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

It doesn't crash every time I am trying to redraw the map. What can I do to debug this error and find the actual cause?

Comment: Could you please print region value when it is crashing.

Comment: @Daljeet 
MKCoordinateRegion region= MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,distance,distance);
The value of distance is 2000 and the location is a typical location in a Europe country

Comment: thats fine just print value of region and put a breakpoint there...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was calling setRegion twice. Removing the second call fixed this issue.